# Swift 3 : How can I get the Array from the String

Tags: arrays, swift, string, swift3, string-conversion

Actually I got the address field string from the api like "District-1   1656-Union-Street   Eureka  707-445-6600", so I need to convert into Array.

Expected Result :

> ["District-1", "1656-Union-Street", "Eureka", "707-445-6600"]

As I can get the Array from the `components` method using space as a separator.

```
//Code
var getAddress = addInfo.components(separatedBy: " ")

//Result
["District-1", "", "", "1656-Union-Street", "", "", "Eureka", "", "707-445-6600"]
```

But the problem is that it will return the empty object also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply the `split` method for accomplished the task.

For i.e.

```
var addInfo = "District-1   1656-Union-Street   Eureka  707-445-6600"
var getAddress = addInfo.characters.split(separator: " ", omittingEmptySubsequences: true).map(String.init)

//Result
["District-1", "1656-Union-Street", "Eureka", "707-445-6600"]
```

> **omittingEmptySubsequences** : If false, an empty subsequence is returned
>   in the result for each consecutive pair of separator elements in the
>   collection and for each instance of separator at the start or end of
>   the collection. If true, only nonempty subsequences are returned. The
>   default value is true.

For more information please review the [link](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/array/1689391-split)